# Vuex. При обновлении страницы store сбрасывается в исходное состояние

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Здравствуйте, новичок во Vue. Пришлось разрабатывать крупное SPA на Vue и использовать при этом Vuex.

---

Имеется вот такое хранилище:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isAuth: false
    },
    actions: {
        signIn ({ commit }, isAuth) {
            commit('signIn', isAuth);
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        signIn (state, isAuth) {
            state.isAuth = !state.isAuth;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        signIn: state => state.isAuth
    }, 
})
```

При авторизации на сайте пользователь получает token и изменяется состояние хранилища таким образом:

```
this.$store.dispatch('signIn', true);
```

Если пользователь не автоматизирован, то в header есть только одна кнопка Login. При получении token и изменении состояния хранилища кнопка Login пропадает и появляется кнопка Sign out. Это всё реализовано при помощи вычисляемых значений:

```
computed: {    
        auth () {
            return this.$store.getters.signIn
        }  
    }
```

В самом шаблоне прописано условие:

```
<v-btn class="btn" v-if="auth" @click="signOut">Sign out</v-btn>

<v-btn class="btn" v-if="!auth" @click="login">Log in</v-btn>
```

Теперь сама суть проблемы. При авторизации и получении токена состояние хранилища меняется, кнопка Login пропадает и появляется Sign out, `isAuth` становится `true`. Вроде бы всё хорошо. Но при обновлении страницы в браузере хранилище возвращается в исходное состояние, то есть `isAuth: false`. Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы состояние сохранялось после обновления страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае нужно сохранять данные об авторизации например в localstorage.

Comment: Cогласен с вами, я так и сделал при авторизации сохраняю token в localStorage: 'let token = response.body.token; localStorage.setItem('token', token);'.  Но самой проблемы это не решает. Смысл в store теряется, если мы используем само хранилище браузера. Да и если у меня будет 100 объектов в store, не записывать же мне их в localstorage.

Comment: А зачем записывать все? Достаточно токена. При загрузке приложения смотрите если токен есть, то пытаетесь авторизоваться и в случае успеха подтянуть нужные данные и привести приложение в нужное состояние.

Comment: Ну так используйте https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate и не беспокойтесь за сохранность состояния

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)
См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60900161/22032426

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)